# How to toggle between tabs in visual web developer 2010 expresss

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

ctrl m + ctrl g toggles the controller and view, but is there a shortcut for toggling between open tabs in the ide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it not ctrl+tab, like in the full edition

Comment: Perhaps even... a... bloody fool? :)

Answer (score 2):

With Control + Tab you can cycle trough open tabs